# HAProxy/Websockets why new sockets are constantly being created?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, haproxy

I'm trying to setup Websockets with HAProxy, with the following configuration:
http traffic -> haproxy -> varnish -> nginx -> node
ws traffic -> haproxy -> node

one subdomain has forced ssl so haproxy redirect any http traffic to https. (and ws to wss)

everything is working as expected except one issue, new sockets are constantly being created instead of just one (I can see them being created every few seconds in Chrome's debugging console)

I didn't have this problem when I used Varnish to do the Websockets pipe.

how can I fix this ?

```
global
  daemon

defaults
  mode  http

frontend insecure
 # HTTP
  bind :80

  timeout client 5000

  # acl
  acl is_console hdr_end(host) -i console.mydomain.com
  acl is_client hdr_end(host) -i www.mydomain.com
  acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
  acl is_websocket hdr_beg(Host) -i ws

  # Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
  redirect location https://console.mydomain.com if is_console

  use_backend node_console if is_console is_websocket
  use_backend node_client if is_client is_websocket
  default_backend varnish

frontend secure
 # HTTPS
  bind :443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/console.mydomain.com.pem

  timeout client 5000

  # acl
  acl is_console hdr_end(host) -i console.mydomain.com
  acl is_client hdr_end(host) -i www.mydomain.com
  acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
  acl is_websocket hdr_beg(Host) -i ws

  use_backend dealspot_console if is_console is_websocket
  use_backend dealspot_client if is_client is_websocket
  default_backend varnish

backend varnish
  balance leastconn
  option forwardfor
  timeout server 5000
  timeout connect 4000
  server varnish1 127.0.0.1:6081

backend node_client
  balance leastconn
  option forwardfor
  timeout queue 5000
  timeout server 5000
  timeout connect 5000
  server client_node1 127.0.0.1:3000

backend node_console
  balance leastconn
  option forwardfor
  timeout queue 5000
  timeout server 5000
  timeout connect 5000
  server console_node1 127.0.0.1:3001
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix that by setting 'tunnel timeout' to one day on the backends